# Is there a better way in Spring MVC to pass a cookie in to an endpoint where the cookie name is defined at runtime?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to produce a REST service. Most of my @RequestMappings require a cookie which contains a session ID. The name of the cookie depends on the environment in which the service is deployed. So for example I use 'dev_session' in dev environments and 'prod_session' in production.

As far as I can tell, this rules out using @CookieValue since the name is a constant. Other options I've come up with are:

- Passing in HttpServletRequest and calling getCookies(). This is
  pretty ugly, especially as I would need to do it for about 100
  request mappings
- Use AOP @Around advice to get the HttpServletRequest, find the cookie and then pass it in to target method. I'm not sure if this would work and whether i'd have to have both the cookie value and the HttpServletRequest as a parameter to the target method so that i'd have HttpServletRequest available. Either way, it doesn't seem like a good approach.
- WebArgumentResolver. This is the best option i've come up with and I have it working. I annotate the parameter with a custom annotation @SessionCookie then in WebArgumentResolver.resolveArgument() if the argument has that annotation I return the value of the cookie. Unfortunately it breaks the auto-generated documentation I use as it doesn't recognise the annotation (Swagger-springmvc). Also it still seems rather hard work for something so simple.

So my question is, is there a better way to get hold of a cookie with a name only known at runtime?

Comment: Have you considered using `org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getCookie`?

Comment: Those all sound like reasonable solutions. You say that option 3 feels like hard work, so I'm curious - in an ideal world, how would you want to express such a thing?

Comment: I hadn't, and it's a useful thing to know about, however I don't think it helps in this case as it's basically the same as my first option.

Comment: @skaffman, Ideally i'd like to use SpEL, so something like @CookieValue("${sessionCookieName}")

Comment: Why not use a [HandleInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html), which would be the only one to extract the cookie value from the request, and would store it into an injectable, request-scoped bean? All the controllers would simply have to autowire this request-scoped bean to get the cookie value.

Comment: How do you define the environment? By activating a profile?